# PostgreSQL query to check if a row is referenced from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I have one master table A, and two different sub tables (B, C) which is referenced by foreign key in table A, I want to check if a row exists with foreign key fk-1 in tables B or C.

I tried by selecting rows from A with exists clause on B & C which are selected using the fk-1 further OR'ed together and found the result.

```
SELECT A.id FROM A where A.id = fk-1 AND
(
    EXISTS (select B.id from B where B.fk_1 = fk-1)
    OR EXISTS (select C.id from C where C.fk_1 = fk-1)
);
```

Can this be optimised or is there any better ways to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is a more efficient (or simpler) way.

Comment: Hi, what is the performance impact of OR being used multiple times when more tables need to be added in exists clause?

Answer (score 1):

For a single check that is the fastest given you indexed A.id, B.fk_1 and C.fk_1

A common pitfall is calling this SQL for every single row you might want to check. The check can be way faster if all rows are checked at once. (Faster per row checked)

So in case you want to check a bunch of them at the same time, you could do:

```
SELECT A.id FROM A WHERE A.id IN (
    SELECT B.fk_1 FROM B [WHERE xxx] 
    UNION SELECT C.fk_1 FROM C [WHERE xxx])
```

Use [WHERE xxx] to place a WHERE to filter the relevant results you might want.
One recommeded check would be "WHERE B.fk_1 IS NOT NULL" to filter out records without FK.

Comment: Columns are indexed, its for a single check. Thanks for pointer on how to check a bunch of them.

Comment: `A common pitfall is calling this SQL for every single row you might want to check.`  WRONG. (where did you learn that?)

Comment: It depends on the actual SQL and how its planned, but for the general case it's true: Scanning a B-Tree index for many items requires way less time than starting the scan over every single time. And, don't forget, for every SQL you have to pay a penalty for round-trips, parsing time and planning time. So, unless the 1 row version has a way better planning than the many rows version, the many rows version is faster (which in my experience is 95% of the time).